# Pointer to function seg faulting

Tags: c, dll, segmentation-fault, function-pointers, dlsym

I'm building a user defined shell. I have an array of pointers to functions -- that is, an array full of shared library functions that can be invoked at any point.

I typedef here

```
typedef void (*func_ptr)(char **);
func_ptr function;
void *pointers_to_functions[64];
```

I have debugged and confirmed that my initializations of placing the pointers into the array is working properly, but here's the code for safe measures...

```
void initialize_built_in(){
    void *handle;
    char *error;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        handle = dlopen(builtin_files[i], RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);
        if (!handle) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
            exit(1);
        }
        pointers_to_functions[i] = dlsym(handle, builtin_functions[i]);
        if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%c\n", *error);
            exit(1);
        }

        if (dlclose(handle) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%c\n", *dlerror());
            exit(1);
         }
    }
}
```

Here's where the seg fault occurs -- when I invoke the function

```
int execute_built_in(char **argv){

    int i;
    //scan through the builtin_functions strings to find the correct index of pointers_to_functions - that is, they have the same ordering
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(builtin_functions); i++){
        if (!strcmp(argv[0], builtin_functions[i])){
            //the index has been found
            function = pointers_to_functions[i];
            function(argv); //execute function
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

My shared library does indeed take argv as a parameter -- so I don't believe this is the problem.

As I said, debugging I see that the array of pointers is filled with addresses. I suppose it could be an incorrect address somehow, but I'm at a brick wall here.

Any ideas?

---

So I tested the pointer to function call be defining my own function type (void *) in the same file.

```
func_ptr function;
void *testfunction(char **);
void *pointers_to_functions[64] = {testfunction};
```

where the function just prints something out to the shell

then I added a condition in the execute_function function to force execution...

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(builtin_functions); i++){
        if (i == 0){
            function = pointers_to_functions[1];
            char *bleh[] = {"bleh"};
            function(bleh);
        }
        if (!strcmp(argv[0], builtin_functions[i])){
            //the index has been found
            function = pointers_to_functions[i];
            function(argv); //execute function
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

and it works `WOOHOO!`

So I either have a problem with my dynamic linking, which I can't see. Or with my shared library -- which is unlikely because I've already built successful libraries that work with another shell code of the same project.

So, what's wrong with my dynamic linking?

Here's an example shared library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct NewBuiltIn{
    char *CommandName[64];
    char *FunctionName[64];
    char *AnalyzerName[64];
};

struct NewBuiltIn pluggin_method = {{"cd", "cd", ""}};

void cd(char *argv[]) {
    if(chdir(argv[1]) < 0){
        printf("There was an error in changing your directory. Please check the path name and retry.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code exactly causes the seg fault? The debugger should tell you precisely.

Comment: where the function is called -- `function(argv)`

Comment: `sizeof(builtin_functions)` needs to be `sizeof(builtin_functions) / sizeof builtin_functions[0]`

Comment: No that's not it. The loop executes the correct number of times. And builtin_functions is an array of strings. The problem is in the function call. The function I'm calling takes argv as an argument too

Comment: I didn't say that's the root cause. But it's definetely a problem. `sizeof(builtin_functions)` will give you the size of the array in bytes not the number of elements. Fix it, re-test and then update your code if the problem is still occuring. Otherwise no decent dev will be able to take their eyes past that glaring bug to look at anything else.

Comment: Ok I can do that, thanks for the help. I assumed that would be a problem but overlooked it for the time being. Any ideas why it would be seg faulting? BTW I'll update the code later, I'm afk

Comment: Does `function` point to what you expect? That is, does the debugger show the `function` value is indeed pointing to the handler function for the command?

Comment: Gdb shows that function is pointing towards an address. And in fact the pointers_to_functions array has addresses that are contiguous. So it seems it's pointing to the correct place

Comment: In gdb run `list *function`. That command prints out the code around that address. See if it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Add a function of yours in the pointers_to_functions array, and arrange to have it called from the same loop. If that works, then either: the library is not loaded, the library function does not have the right prototype, or is not using the same calling convention.

Comment: so I'm back at keyboard and I did this, and while debugging if I try to step into the function that I defined in the same file it seg faults. Which tells me something's wrong with the way I am calling the function. But all the sources I can see show the same syntax. Maybe something is wrong with my arguments to the pointer to functions. I have updated the post with this code

Comment: function = pointers_to_functions[0];  // *not* [1]

Comment: doh stupid mistake! lol it's late here. Ok so now it IS executing the function which means something is wrong with the way I am compiling my shared libraries (unlikely because I've already had success), the dynamic linking (likely) or my shared library itself. Check post for more code

Comment: Your 'cd' uses argv[1] - not argv[0] - but the sample code has 'bleh[]' defined with a single string. Make sure you pass an argv[] with at least 2 elements when calling 'cd'. P.S. You should also edit your original question with the 'pointers_to_functions[0];' change to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your init function is wrong:
you perform a `dlclose(handle)` which causes all the lib you loaded to be unmapped from memory, and obviously, the functions you expect to call are flying away.
You must keep the lib mapped to memory until you completely finished using the function pointers you stored.

You can probably check this by observing that the address that segfaults actually lies in the library mapped segment (in /proc/your_app_pid/maps)

Comment: It should be mentioned that dlclose will only cause the library to be unloaded if the reference count drops to 0 (it's entirely possible that there could be another dlopen elsewhere in the code that's not shown, for example). Anyway, that's a good guess, and it's why I said "*either: the library is not loaded*" in a previous comment.

Comment: What happens if I want to have multiple function pointers in my array? Will leaving the mapping open be acceptable for multiple function pointers? I hope this makes sense

Comment: yes as long a you keep the handle valid, any symbol you get with dlsym() will remain valid. (BTW the comment from dxiv is right there can be situations where pointers remain valid afer dlclose because the lib remains opened by some other part of the code)